# Load items from API in reverse order

Tags: api, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a react native app that is retrieving APIs.

However, instead of retrieving from item[0] to item[93], I wanted to reverse it so that it presents the data from item[93] at the top, followed by item[92], etc.

Hence, I tried to include this in my flatlist:

```
inverted={true}
```

However, in doing so, when i load the app, it will still load from [0], but keep including the next items above it over and over.

How do I also load the info from item[93] to item[0]?

Thanks so much!

My flatlist looks like that:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.background}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          inverted={true}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (

            <Card>
              <CardItem>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                  <Image style={styles.profilepic}
                    source={{
                      uri: item.links.mission_patch
                      // from API docs 
                    }}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.userinfo}>
                  <Text style={styles.content}>
                    Flight Number: {item.flight_number}
                    Mission Name: {item.mission_name}
                    {item.details}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `Array.reverse()` like so:

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource.reverse()}
//
```